# Why does curl failures finding the ssl certificate work intermittently?

Tags: facebook, ssl, curl, libcurl, intermittent

I think I have now a good grasp of why you need to either have the ssl certificate bundle when pulling content from a https api like facebook. But my question is: Why does this work sometimes even without the certificate and some others not? 
Seems to me that libcurl has a way to overcome this problem on its own.

Anybody knows why or how this happens? Anybody had the same experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of cUrl with regards to SSL certificates depends on the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER option.
Assuming you use PHP, you can use the function [curl_setopt](http://php.net/curl_setopt) to change the value of this option.

I have only superficial knowledge of SSL but it seems that cUrl behaves in the following way:
0 means no checking, 1 checks if the certificate is legit, and 2 checks also checks if the certificate is issued to the correct hostname.

You can 'turn off annoying errors' by setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to 0, but this means that you cannot be sure that you will have a connection to the correct server, as anyone may [spoof the DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_spoofing). So doing so is very dangerous.

The official facebook php sdk supplies its own certificate using [CURLOPT_CAINFO](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L880), but only when curl could not validate the certificate on its own. I do not know why the developers of the facebook sdk would make this conditional; perhaps because reading certificates might be expensive.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this.
I think I didn't explain myself correctly. What I'm looking to know is about the fact that if you leave settings untouched and you by default  curl will look for a ssl certificate... sometimes it will NOT cough an error on php and things work fine for no reason. 

I guess my question is: Why does it only happen sometimes? Or is it just me?

Comment: I believe this has something to do with so-called 'root certificates' that are available to openssl. On debian, these are stored in /usr/lib/ssl/certs.

Comment: The certificate of graph.facebook.com/ is issued by DigiCert (www.digicert.com). In my directory, I have a number of certificate files with that name (DigiCert_*.pem). Moving those files doesn't seem to stop curl from recognising facebook.com though; maybe the certificates are cached somehow?

Comment: Moving all the files to a temporary directory seems to inhibit curl from recognising the certificate. The connection is restored when I use the -k or --insecure flag, or when I reinstate the .pem files.
Also, check out the [curl documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) :-)